# Download entire localStorage as file

Tags: javascript, performance, functional-programming, json, ecmascript-6

I would like to download the entire contents from `localStorage` to a json file (in a "clear" formatting).

I've tried this and it works perfectly. However, I'm not sure it's very performant.

If possible I'd like to keep the inline syntax.

```
const download = () => (
  Object.assign(document.createElement("a"), {
    href: `data:application/JSON, ${encodeURIComponent(
      JSON.stringify(
        Object.keys(localStorage).reduce(
          (obj, k) => ({ ...obj, [k]: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(k)) }),
          {}
        ),
        null,
        2
      )
    )}`,
    download: "your_history",
  }).click()
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Code Style

Though it is brief, the function has consistent indentation and isn’t too complex. However it does look a bit “pyramid shaped” - also known as [“callback hell”](http://callbackhell.com).

## Performance

> *However, I'm not sure it's very performant*

If performance is a concern, then consider a regular `for...in` loop instead of the functional approach with `Object.keys().reduce()`, though it may be difficult to keep the inline syntax.

## Functionality

This code seems congruent with most of the answers to [*Download JSON object as a file from browser* on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19721439/1575353). There is at least [one answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45594892/1575353) that mentions a library [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) which abstracts all of the logic of saving the file. Unless adding a library is more overhead than desired, that could allow great simplification and [compatibility with more browsers](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js#supported-browsers).

## Usability

It appears the code only works with values that are objects or arrays, but would throw an error for some values like strings.

Take for example: setting a localStorage item to a string literal:

```
localStorage.setItem('username', 'Gibberish');
```

Yet when such a value is parsed using `JSON.parse()` an error occurs:

```js
JSON.parse('Gibberish')
```

It might be wise to update the code at `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(k))` to ensure the item is not a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote 3 functions (as seen in the code below) and tested them for performance in multiple browsers.

I was hoping that `download1` would work faster than `download0`, but after testing in Firefox and Chrome, it turned out that `download2` was faster.

Firefox:

- Function download0: 13846 ms
- Function download1: 14584 ms
- Function download2: 13432 ms

Chrome:

- Function download0: 16339.52294921875 ms
- Function download1: 20340.077880859375 ms
- Function download2: 14501.512939453125 ms

It's also unexpected that **Firefox** is faster than **Chrome**

```js
  localStorage.setItem('k', '{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": [1,2,3]}') 

  const download0 = () => (
      encodeURIComponent(
        JSON.stringify(
          Object.keys(localStorage).reduce(
            (obj, k) => ({ ...obj, [k]: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(k)) }),
            {}
          ),
          null,
          2
        )
      )
  )

  const download1 = () => (
      encodeURIComponent(
        JSON.stringify(
          Object.entries(localStorage).reduce(
            (obj, [k, v]) =>  ({...obj, [k]: JSON.parse(v)}),
            {}
          ),
          null,
          2
        )
      )
  )


  const download2 = () => (
    encodeURIComponent(
      JSON.stringify(
        (function(){
          const o = {};
          for (const k of Object.keys(localStorage)){
            o[k] = JSON.parse(localStorage[k])
          }
          return o
        }())  
        , null, 2)
    )
  ) 


  for (const op of [download0, download1, download2 ]){
    console.time(`Function ${op.name}`);
    for(let i = 1000000; i != 0; i--){
      op()
    }
    console.timeEnd(`Function ${op.name}`)
  }
```

As an explanation of the code, I really don't know why Chrome is running slower. The second attempt was based on the assumption that working directly with `localStorage` is not very efficient, but it also turned out that extracting entries is less efficient than just getting keys. Why is `reduce` less efficient than a `for of` loop? Because there is a  destruction `...obj` (in fact, the creation of a new object) - I find it less efficient than just adding a key.

Comment: Please explain the various differences. Just dumping your code isn't considered an answer, code review requires more. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks for your updates, +1 upvote