# Randomly set styles with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, array, random, ecmascript-6

I have created a function which randomly sets styles using CSS selectors. Right now it returns a random item from an array. The program also works with shorthand properties (such as `font`).

**Could my code be improved and run more efficiently?**

```js
const setRandomStyles = (obj) => {
  console.time("Executed in ");
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([target, styles]) =>
    document
      .querySelectorAll(target)
      .forEach((element) =>
        Object.assign(
          element.style,
          Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(styles).map(([key, values]) => [
              key,
              Array.isArray(values[0])
                ? values.map((e) => e[~~(Math.random() * e.length)]).join(" ")
                : values[~~(Math.random() * values.length)],
            ])
          )
        )
      )
  );
  console.timeEnd("Executed in ");
};

setRandomStyles({
  "*": {
    color: ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"],
    backgroundColor: ["yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"],
    font: [["italic", "bold"], [...Array(40).keys()].map((i) => i + "px"), ["cursive", "sans-serif", "consolas"]],
  },
});
```

*You can also propose better code to set random styles in js.*
Thanks!

Comment: How many browsers are you targeting?  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) says that "some older browsers have not implemented NodeList.forEach()".

Comment: @Teepeemm, I go for the fastest and most "modern" solution (so using ES6)

Comment: This solution is very nice.  The only thing I might consider is pulling `~~(Math.random() * e.length` into a utility function `randElement(arr)`, though the phrase is so short the duplication hardly matters.

Comment: @Jonah so my code is already optimized and does not need any improvements ? (appart from the suggestion you mentioned)

Comment: From a readability perspective, yes it is imo.  I did not analyze it from a performance perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Code Style

This code looks very identical to the code in your recent question [*Download entire localStorage as file*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/273868/120114). Like I mentioned in [my answer there](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/274175/120114) it does look a bit "pyramid shaped". I see this basic pattern

```
function
  Object.entries().forEach
    Object.assign
      Object.fromEntries
        Object.entries().map
          map || item
```

That is 6+ levels of indentation! It is a good thing you are only using two spaces instead of four (or even worse- tabs) - otherwise the line lengths would be quite a bit longer.

Still it doesn't seem totally unreadable.

> ### Could my code be improved and run more efficiently?

#### Efficiency

One could perhaps improve efficiency by switching to basic `for` loops. While it strays from the functional programming techniques, the example snippet below uses `for...of` loops, which still uses an iterator so it isn't as fast as a regular `for` loop but that will likely not be noticeable for small DOM trees. It also eliminates the need to call `Object.assign()` and `Object.fromEntries()` as it assigns to the style directly in each iteration. While it contains the same complexity (i.e. two loops nested within a loop) the indentation levels are fewer and there are fewer functions executed per iteration.

```js
const setRandomStyles = obj => {
  console.time("Executed in ");
  for (const [target, styles] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    for (const element of document.querySelectorAll(target)) {
      for (const [key, values] of Object.entries(styles)) {
        element.style[key] = Array.isArray(values[0])
          ? values.map((e) => e[~~(Math.random() * e.length)]).join(" ")
          : values[~~(Math.random() * values.length)];
      }
    }
  }
  console.timeEnd("Executed in ");
};

setRandomStyles({
  "*": {
    color: ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"],
    backgroundColor: ["yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"],
    font: [["italic", "bold"], [...Array(40).keys()].map((i) => i + "px"), ["cursive", "sans-serif", "consolas"]],
  },
});
```

#### Arrow function syntax simplification

While it may not be a big difference, "Multiple params require parentheses"<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#basic_syntax)</sup> but if an arrow function has just one parameter then the parentheses can be omitted (as was done in the snippet above).

For Example:

> ```
> const setRandomStyles = (obj) => {
> ```

can be simplified to:

```
const setRandomStyles = obj => {
```

And

> ```
> (e) => e[~~(Math.random() * e.length)]
> ```

can be simplified to:

```
e => e[~~(Math.random() * e.length)]
```

#### Simplify selectors

While `style` is a [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) it may just be for demonstration purposes, the selector `*` applies to all elements within the HTML page - including tags that likely don't need to have style attributes - e.g. `<html>`, `<head>`, `<link>`, `<meta>`, etc..

For example, I ran the code on a sample HTML page on jsbin.com and it showed this HTML (simplified and formatted for brevity):

```
<html style="color: red; background-color: violet; font: bold 6px sans-serif;">
  <head style="color: green; background-color: blue; font: italic 3px sans-serif;">
    <script style="color: orange; background-color: violet; font: italic 21px consolas;"> /* script source */</script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" style="color: violet; background-color: violet; font: bold 29px sans-serif;">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" style="color: violet; background-color: violet; font: bold 26px consolas;">
    <title style="color: orange; background-color: yellow; font: bold 6px cursive;">JS Bin</title>
    <style id="jsbin-css" style="color: violet; background-color: blue; font: bold 20px cursive;">
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="color: blue; background-color: yellow; font: italic 14px consolas;">
    sample text
    <div style="color: violet; background-color: yellow; font: bold 22px sans-serif;">Hey there dude</div>
    <script style="color: green; background-color: violet; font: italic 8px cursive;">/* script source */ </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks although try pasting your code in the dev console of this page and you will get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'color')`. Why is that happening ?

Comment: Apparently a similar error happens with the original code: _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object_. It appears to be related to the MathJax elements on the CR pages. Run `document.querySelector('math')` and it should reveal an element `<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"></math>`. I'm not really familliar with  [that namespace](https://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML/) but it seems such an element has no support for `style` in its [attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/chapter2.html#interf.toplevel).

Comment: the arrow function simplification isnt good practice imo. Since it introduces inconsistency when you have more than one arg. IMO, its best to stay consistent and always use parents. It is also more clear and readable that way, as it conveys the nature of it better.

Comment: Just one more thing, do you think there could be a better way to set random styles using js? For example in the way the function is used.

Comment: @Gibberish there likely could be a better way. Also - there are ways to get random colors - e.g. [generating hex values](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/random-hex-color/) instead of using a finite list of color names